# Oxygen sensor connector harness side

Tags: electrical

Does anyone know where one can buy oxygen sensor harness connector for 96 dodge neon Vin C SOHC

Comment: The dealer should carry them. Or a used autoparts place could get you one/you cut it off yourself. Or you could call the dealer, get the part number and look it up online to see if you can get it cheaper. If you call the dealer make sure you have your VIN on hand.

Answer (score 1):

Go down to your local Dodge dealer, they'll have them.  If you want to go a bit cheaper, you can, as Ben suggested, get it at a used autoparts place.  If you prefer to go online, check out [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/O2-Oxygen-Sensor-New-Dodge-Neon-Plymouth-1995-1996-OS5231-/131783933825?hash=item1eaeef3f81:g:s2sAAOSwHoFXr~fg&vxp=mtr) or [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B805HDQ).  (Links are links to the part you need.)